# I don't understand how these two variables are proportionate

Tags: sicp

*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* section 1.2.1 Linear Recursion and Iteration:

> Compare the two processes... each requires a number of steps proportional to n to compute n!

The two processes are specified by

```lisp
(define (factorial n)
  (if (= n 1)
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))

;; This is the linear recursive process
```

```lisp
(define (factorial n)
 (define (iter product counter)
   (if (> counter n)
       product
       (iter (* counter product)
             (+ counter 1))))
 (iter 1 1))

;; This is the linear iterative process
```

My question is: how do both processes require a number of steps proportional to n to compute n! ?

Comment: It means that if we want to compute the factorial of `n`, we have to iterate more or less `n` times: `c * n` times, with `c` an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st process;
you have to do these steps in one recursive loop:

```
- check if n equals 1
- multiply n with (factorial (- n 1))
  if we split it a little, it includes (- n 1) and a function call and a multiplication.
```

Let just roughly count these as 4 steps.

And because you have to do these 4 steps until n = 1, totally it is 4*n steps. so it is proportional to n.
(let's ignore some details, e.g., processing of n=1 case is a little bit different because when n is large enough, it can be ignored)

The 2nd one is the same

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the procedures will keep running until a certain condition is met.

- Recursive process will keep invoking the `(factorial)` procedure and decreasing `n` until `n=1`
- Iterative process will keep increasing the `counter` variable until `counter > n`

The larger the value of `n` the longer it will take to satisfy each termination check.

**Example:** `(factorial 1000)` will take longer than `(factorial 10)` simply because getting 1000 to 1 will take 999 steps reducing `n` by 1 every time `factorial` is invoked (in the recursive process). On the other hand, getting 10 to 1 will take you just 9 steps.

Hope that answers your question.